# Como faço para bloquear o RadioButton selecionado?

Tags: java, android

Eu criei um `RadioGroup` com 3 `RadioButton` interno, porem não consigo encaixar um código que faça com que o usuário ao selecionar um `RadioButton` seja impedido de selecionar outro.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="O que você coloca em uma torradeira?"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rgRespostas">
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/rbResposta1"
            android:text="Torrada"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/rbResposta2"
            android:text="Bolo"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/rbResposta3"
            android:text="Pão"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"/>

    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

O setEnabled não bloqueia o radioButton. Eu consegui resolver de outro jeito.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int checkedID) {
            if (checkedID == R.id.rb1){
                for(int i = 0; i < radioGroup.getChildCount(); i++){
                    ((RadioButton)radioGroup.getChildAt(i)).setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode desabilitar os outros radios button radioButton.setEnabled(false);
Caso não seja isso que você imaginou so falar!

Comment: E como faço isso? Tipo, eu crio um método na Activity e vinculo ao id da RadioGroup e crio a seguinte condição: Se usuário clicar em em rbResposta1, então desabilite a opção rbResposta2 e rbResposta3. Algo assim?

Comment: Seria mais fácil desabilitar o RadioGroup.

Comment: voce pode usar o metodo OnCheckedChangeListener e dentro dele colocar                                                                                                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                rbResposta2.setEnabled(false);